# A problem on finding conditional PDF

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability, density-function

Given that $X,Y$ are two continuous Random variables with joint PDF given by
$$f_{XY}(x, y)=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
\frac{1}{2} e^{-x}, & |y| \leq x, x>0 \\
0 & \text { else }
\end{array}\right.$$
Find $$f_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y)$$
My try:

I have figured out the marginal density function of $Y$ as :

$$f_{Y}(y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{2} e^{-y}, & y>0 \\
\frac{1}{2} e^{y}, & y<0
\end{array}\right\}$$

Now we know that $$f_{X\mid Y}(x \mid y)=\frac{f_{XY}(x, y)}{f_{Y}(y)}$$

Now i am confused how to do the division?

Comment: You can write $f_Y(y) = \frac12 e^{-|y|}$ and then divide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, simply express

$$f_Y(y)=\frac{e^{-|y|}}{2}$$

Thus

$$f_{X|Y}(x|y)=e^{|y|-x}$$

$x\ge|y|$

It's a truncated negative exponential